# How to Croppie one image uploaded

Tags: javascript, html, django, croppie

I have been looking the Croppie library: https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

But I can't realize how to use it properly if I upload one image (the webpage needs a bit more info). How can I set my uploaded image inside of the croppie? I have tried bind or other ways but I can't show it inside.

I leave you here my code (almost the same saw it in the official page):

HTML

```
               <div class="form-group">
                 <div id="image_user_profile" class="custom-input-file text-center">
                       <input id="fileInput" name="fileInput" type="file" size="1" class="input-file"/>
                       <img id="img_user" alt="Upload user image" src="{{ user.get_picture }}" width="50%" height="50%" style="background-color: #eee; min-height:100px"/>
                 </div>
               </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div id="img-user-prueba2">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
var uploadCrop = $('#img-user-prueba2').croppie({
            enableExif: true,
            viewport: {
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            },

            boundary: {
                width: 300,
                height: 300
            }
        });


$('input[name=fileInput]').change(function(ev) {
            RegisterTraveler.readURL(this);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern:

```
import Croppie from 'croppie/croppie';

var croppie = new Croppie(<your element>, {boundary: etc...});
croppie.bind({url: <your image>});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
<script>
$('.demo').croppie({
    url: 'demo/demo-1.jpg',
});
</script>
```